# Rao-Blackwell Theorem Proof

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

[Rao-Blackwell Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P58v.png)

Based on the Rao-Blackwell Theorem Proof shown in the image above, I have a question regarding the portion boxed in red:

Why is $Var(\hat\theta|T) = 0$ if $\hat\theta=E(\hat\theta|T)$?

I understand that in this case, $\hat\theta$ is a function of $T$, but I don't see why this implies $Var(\hat\theta|T)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the section in red.
We have $\mbox{Var}(\hat{\theta}) > \mbox{Var}(\tilde{\theta})$ or $\mbox{Var}(\hat\theta | T) = 0$. Suppose $\mbox{Var}(\hat{\theta}) = \mbox{Var}(\tilde{\theta})$ (there is no $\leq$ because of theorem B), then $\mbox{Var}(\hat\theta |T)=0$ implies $\hat\theta = \hat\theta (T)$, which in turn implies $\tilde\theta = \hat\theta$.

My guess is there is mis-understanding about the 'unless' operator. This is thoroughly dissected in, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614481/the-translations-of-unless-and-except-into-symbolic-logic?rq=1).

Also, I think you are mixing up 'if' with 'only if'. For details, see, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68293/what-is-the-difference-between-only-if-and-iff).

Comment: Hi Alvin, thank you for the reply! Based on your answer, I would like to ask why does $Var(\hat\theta|T)=0$ imply $\hat\theta = \hat\theta(T)$?