# Is "William only eats icecream when the sun is shining" a biimplication?

Tags: logic, logic-translation, article-writing

> William only eats icecream when the sun is shining
>
> Let $P(t)$ be the sun is shining at time $t.$
> Let $Q(t)$ be William is eating an icecream at time $t.$
>
> Which implication is there between $P(t)$ and $Q(t)?$

My friend has suggested that it is a biimplication, but I disagree, since it would then mean that every time the sun is shining William would be eating an icecream.

I have suggested that it is instead $Q(t)→P(t),$ since we know that if William is eating icecream then the sun will be shining.

Comment: The mathematician RL Moore took the position that “only if” should mean “if and only if”. The idea is that “A only if B” is a stronger statement than “A if B”. Not only are we told that “A if B”, but we are given a little extra information: “A *only* if B”.  So if someone thinks your example is a biimplication, they’re not crazy. However, mathematicians have adopted the convention that “A only if B” means “A implies B”.

Comment: Pedantically, I have to point out that different positioning of "only" within the sentence can make the sentence mean different things. IMHO, in the position "only" occupies in this sentence ("William only eats ice cream"), it attaches to the verb "eats" and excludes any other actions William might perform on the ice cream. William only eats ice cream; he doesn't throw it.

Comment: The only way I see to get a biimplication is if you take "only" to mean that eating ice cream is the only thing that William does if the sun is shining. But that's a strange way to understand the sentence.

Comment: @HenryWoody I believe the rigorous way to write the statement is "William eats ice cream only if the sun is shining" and then it becomes an obvious instance of the "only if" construct.

Comment: All we really can say for sure about William is that he never eats ice cream when the sun isn't shining.  If the sun is shining, he might be eating ice cream, or he might not be.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I agree with littleO that "A only if B" should be equivalent to "A implies B". Surely "A if and only if B" should be equivalent to the conjunction "(A if B) and (A only if B)".  The first of these, "A, if B", may be rewritten as "if B, then A", so that one is certainly "B implies A".  The other one, then, must be "A implies B".  Thus "A only if B" is equivalent to "A implies B".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[@b00n Het’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4767080/2439) is short and sweet and correct; but I’ll expand on it a bit, to back it up and consider the complications raised in [@ryang’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4767095/2439).

The key issue is that ***only* in natural English is a bit subtle in several ways, and sometimes ambiguous.**  The main ambiguity is that *only* doesn’t have to directly precede the specific item it’s governing — it usually precedes the main verb.  So for instance *William only mows the lawn on Mondays* can potentially be read as:

1. [*only* governs *Mondays*] It’s only on Mondays that William mows the lawn (not on other days).
2. [*only* governs *the lawn*] It’s only the lawn that William mows on Mondays (not the field beyond).
3. [*only* governs *mows*]  The only thing William does to the lawn on Mondays is mowing it (not raking it).
4. [*only* governs *mows the lawn*] The only thing William does on Mondays is mows the lawn (then he goes straight back to bed).

In practice, usually it’s clear from context which reading is the intended one — and when it wouldn’t be clear, then speakers do place *only* directly with the phrase it governs, and say for instance *William mows the lawn only on Mondays*.  However, as long the intended reading is clear from context, *only* prefers to precede the main verb — and so when *only* is in this position, it should be read as governing whichever subsequent part of the phrase is semantically most natural.  So in *William only eats ice cream on Mondays*, other readings are in principle possible, but **it’s semantically clear that the intended reading is *William eats ice cream only on Mondays***.

The other is to what extent *only* entails that the thing in question happens at all.  If I say “I’ve only been to Brazil twice”, you will rightly conclude that I have been to Brazil twice.  If I say “I only visit democratic countries”, you will conclude that I have probably visited *some* democratic countries — but not that I’ve visited *all* of them.  So this positive entailment is present but subtle; as such, it’s hard to judge whether it’s part of the logical content of the *only* sentence, or just [implicature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature).  In formal usage (mathematical and some legal), it’s well-established that the positive entailment is not taken as part of the logical content; in other contexts, the positive entailment is usually analysed as implicature, but is at least arguably part of the logical content. **But in any case, the positive claim entailed is only existential, not universal.**

So *William only eats ice cream on Mondays* has a couple of reasonable readings; writing $P(t)$ for “William is eating ice cream at time $t$ and $Q(t)$ for “$t$ is a Monday” as you suggest, these are:

1. $\forall t\ P(t) \Rightarrow Q(t)$, “the only time William may eat ice cream is on Mondays”
2. $(\forall t\ P(t) \Rightarrow Q(t)) \wedge (\exists t\ Q(t) \wedge P(t))$ “the only time William may eat ice cream is on Mondays; and he sometimes does eat it on Mondays”

The first of these is the more standard reading, especially in formal or semi-formal contexts.  The second reading is also defensible in natural contexts.  But **neither of these is a bi-implication; the potential bi-implicative reading $(\forall t\ P(t) \Leftrightarrow Q(t))$, “at all times, William is eating ice cream precisely if it’s Monday”, is not justified either by natural usage or formal conventions.**

Comment: The English grammar analysis is important. +1.

Answer (score 13):

Indeed you are right.

The sun might be shining without William eating an icecream.

Comment: Just wondering how unhealthy William gets if this was a biimplication lol

Comment: I wanted to include that to remark the absurdity of the bi-implication :D

Answer (score 2):

> Let $P(t)$ be the sun is shining at time $t.$
> Let $Q(t)$ be William is eating an icecream at time $t.$

- William eats icecream [**only when**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4709862/21813) the sun is shining

  $\forall t\big( Q(t)→P(t)\big).$
- William eats icecream **precisely when** the sun is shining

  $\forall t\big(Q(t)\leftrightarrow P(t)\big).$

> > William **only** eats icecream when the sun is shining

The sentence $$\text{William eats icecream when the sun is shining}$$ contains 9 possible positions to insert the modifier ‘only’, all legitimate, with no pair of resulting sentences having exactly the same set of possible readings (to disambiguate, we typically rely on context, common sense, [word stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)) and pausing).

Every technically correct reading of the quoted sentence gives that *if* the sun is shining, *then* William eats ice cream but doesn't, say, donate ice cream. None is equivalent to either of the above formulae or even $\forall t\big( P(t)→Q(t)\big).$

Now, when perfect grammar is awkward, or at least pedantic, in conversation, we sometimes idiomatically sacrifice accuracy for rhythm. Intending the quoted sentence to mean the first bulleted sentence is arguably such a case.

In any case, this excerpt from [The Grammar According to West](https://dwest.web.illinois.edu/grammar.html) is apropos:

> Live mathematical conversations use many shortcuts that are inappropriate in precise mathematical writing. The context is known by all participants, and shortcuts evolve to save time. Furthermore, the speaker can immediately clarify ambiguity. Without immediate access to the author, written mathematics must use language more carefully. Also, **mathematical concepts are abstract, without context from everyday experience, so the writing must be more consistent to make the meaning clear. Outside mathematics, imprecise writing can still be understood because the objects and concepts discussed are familiar.**

P.S. [The Word ONLY Can’t Go Just Anywhere](https://getitwriteonline.com/placement-of-only/)

Comment: No, "William only eats icecream when the sun is shining" can mean exactly the same as "Wiliam eats icecream only when the sun is shining"; English is ambiguous in this regard.

Comment: @psmears Just because I understand what someone is trying to say doesn't mean they are saying it correctly. In the given sentence, placing the modifier 'only' in each of the 9 possible positions results in a different meaning each way, and due to overlapping meanings there is ambiguity among some of these placements; however, the two placements contrasted in my answer genuinely have distinct meanings.

Comment: My point is that English is ambiguous: the original sentence can mean both "eats icecream (but doesn't do anything else) during sunshine" and "doesn't eat icecream at any other time than during sunshine" and "eats nothing other than icecream during sunshine"; absent further context there's no way to distinguish which is meant. All of those meanings are valid; it's not the case that one is technically more correct than another.

Comment: Ehn, English doesn't use parentheses as much as math/logic people think it could, or should. This is the difference between ((only eats) ice-cream) and (only (eats ice-cream)), and English frequently depends on the listener/reader to choose the most reasonable of the possible interpretations. Me, I'd argue that "eats" and "ice-cream" bind together very tightly, in a way that, say, "juggles" and "ice-cream" don't, and thus the second meaning is what would most commonly be understood.

Comment: @psmears In the given sentence, the word 'only' modifies either "eats" or "eats ice cream" or "eats ice cream when the sun is shining"; since you are bringing up technical correctness, let's agree to disagree that in any of these cases does that sentence technically match your second suggestion (i.e., my first bulleted sentence).

Comment: @psmears When I first read the question that's exactly what I thought it meant -- unless the sun is shining William will not eat ice cream. It's a strange statement, but much less strange than William restricting his diet to only ice cream anytime the sun is out. It's definitely ambiguous grammatically but "common sense" seems to favor one interpretation over the other.

Comment: @Thierry Yes of course our immediate (common-sense) reading of the cited sentence is the first bulleted suggestion, and the cited question clearly can be answered only with that reading. But *grammatically*, [that cited sentence definitely is not meaning that common-sense reading](https://getitwriteonline.com/placement-of-only/).

Comment: @ryang: I see where you're coming from, but unfortunately that approach is based on a misconception. In English - strangely - the scope of an adverb like "only" _doesn't_ have to be the word(s) adjacent to it: indeed its "preferred" position is between the subject (or auxiliary verb if there is one) and the main verb - as in the original example - and its scope can vary. This is acknowledged in the article you linked, which mentions the "potential ambiguity" right at the start. There is nothing technically or grammatically wrong with this usage, and it's employed by many great English writers.

Comment: @psmears1. You keep reiterating your point about natural language's ambiguity as if I did not also acknowledge it at the outset. 2. *Of course* many great writers deliberately break the so-called rules of the English language, which is all about communication, *not* technical correctness. 3. The linked article did *not* claim that 'only' has a preferred position, or that it is between the subject and main verb; it in fact clearly asserts that varying 'only''s position can cause illogic/incorrectness from the intended meaning while acknowledging that common sense can **sometimes** disambiguate.

Comment: @ ryang: I think you’re missing @psmears point, which you say you’ve acknowledged.  People are *not* “breaking the so-called rules of the English language” or “saying it incorrectly” when they intend “I only go to work on Mondays” to mean that they go to work only on Mondays.  They are exactly following the rules of English grammar (in particular, that whatever it modifies, *only* prefers to precede the main verb unless that causes serious ambiguity).  The error is with the person who claims that it should mean “On Mondays, going to work is the only thing I do”.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine The first two sentences of my previous comment were intended to be independent of each other: #2 is *not* an elaboration of #1. psmears's point is straightforward and crystal-clear, and in my initial comments I already proposed to agree to disagree. I was not attempting to represent their position, and also don't wish mine to be misrepresented.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148530/discussion-on-answer-by-ryang-is-william-only-eats-icecream-when-the-sun-is-shi); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 - William **only eats icecream** when the sun is shining

I want you to contrast this sentence with this one:

> 2 - William **eats only icecream** when the sun is shining

In example 1, what's being conveyed is that a specific scenario (eating ice cream) is restricted to a particular precondition (when the sun is shining). In other words, when the condition is not met, there's no ice cream being eaten either.

In example 2, what's being conveyed is that William eats *nothing but icecream* when the sun is shining. He won't eat any other food when the sun's out. If there is no ice cream around he will starve because he will refuse everything else.

I strongly suspect that your friend is parsing the sentence closer to example 2 than example 1. While this is still not a perfect match to the logical claim your friend then goes on to make, it's within the reasonable ballpark of what a human might infer from such a statement being made in an informal conversation.

> but I disagree, since it would then mean that every time the sun is shining William would be eating an icecream.

You are logically correct. But I want to tackle this not from a point of logical accuracy, but rather what a human might understand in a casual conversation.

If I tell you that whenever the sun shines, William refuses to eat any food unless it is ice cream (which is what example 2 tells you); then it's reasonable enough for your friend to interpret this as "William always eats ice cream when the sun is shining", in the sense that they're not saying that he always eats ice cream (i.e. he constantly ingests ice cream) but that he always *chooses* to eat ice cream (i.e. he constantly makes the same choice to ingest ice cream **when** he makes a choice to ingest something).

I suspect your friend is not a logician and is approaching this from a point of semantical intuition. When presented with example 2, their logical inference may not be pedantically correct but it's a reasonable understanding in an informal conversation.

However, in this scenario we're dealing with example 1, not 2. And in example 1, your friend's interpretation is not correct. You are correct in your interpretation of the implication here.

Answer (score 0):

English is ambiguous. Consider:

'A person is a bachelor only if that person is unmarried.'

Here, being unmarried is merely a *necessary* condition for being a bachelor, not sufficient. So we clearly do not want to use a biconditional: just because someone is unmarried doesn't make them a bachelor. Of course, we *can* say that if someone is a bachelor, then they are unmarried. Or, equivalently, that if someone is not unmarried, then they cannot be a bachelor.

But now consider:

'You can take Calculus II only if you have taken Calculus I.'

Here, one can totally see a context where it is clear that this doesn't just mean that having taken Calculus I is necessary for taking Calculus II, but that it is also sufficient: e.g. this statement was given in response to a question as to what the prerequisities are or taking Calculus II .... in which case one would assume that had there been other requirements to taking Calculus II pother than Calculus I, those would have been spelled out. So if that is clear, use a bi-conditional.

When in doubt, though, I also choose the *weaker* reading: any 'P only if Q' at a minimum says that Q is a necessary condition for P. So, if you don't know anything more, then I would just work with that one-way conditional, just to be safe. For the same reason, when someone uses an 'or', and you don;t know whether it was meant as an inclusive or exclusive or, I always use the inclusive or, which is the weaker of the two, so I make sure that I don't assume too much.