# Logic behind continuity definition.

Tags: analysis, logic, continuity

I have a question regarding the definition of continuous functions : from wikipedia and my book : $f$ is said to be continuous at the point $c$ if the following holds:

> For any number $\varepsilon\gt0$, however small, there exists some number $\delta\gt0$ such that for all $x$ in the domain of $f$ with $c − \delta\lt x \lt c + \delta$, the value of $f(x)$ satisfies
>      $$  f(c) - \varepsilon < f(x) < f(c) + \varepsilon.$$

Which can be summarize by $A$ if $B$, which is the same as $B \Rightarrow A$. 
But then my book and wikipedia are assuming that if $f$ is continuous then we have  $f(c) - \varepsilon < f(x) < f(c) + \varepsilon $:

> Fix some $\varepsilon\gt0$. Since f is continuous, there is a $δ > 0$ such that $|f(x) − f(c)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $|x − c| < δ$. This means that
>   $$    f(x) − \varepsilon < f(c) < f(x) + \varepsilon.$$

Which is the same than assuming $A\Rightarrow B$ but our definition of continuity only states that $B\Rightarrow A$. Is there something that I don't get ? Or is my memory of mathematical logic wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The [definition](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/) of a predicate can be expressed as a *bi-conditional* :

> $f$ is *continuous* at point $c$ **iff** for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ in the domain of $f$, *if* $c − \delta\lt x \lt c + \delta$, *then* $f(c) - \varepsilon < f(x) < f(c) + \varepsilon$.

Thus, in order to prove the continuity of $f$ at $c$, we have to choose a positive $\epsilon$ whatever (for all $\epsilon > 0$) and we have to find a suitable positive $\delta$ (there exists $\delta > 0$) such that, for any $x$, the condition "*if* ..., *then* ..." is satisfied.

In this way, we "use" the right-to-left part of the bi-conditional :

> > **if** for all $\epsilon > 0$, ..., **then** $f$ is *continuous* at point $c$.

---

I think that part of the doubt is due to the "correct formalization" of the defining clause.

You can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617562/conditional-statements-only-if) a discussion about the conditional statements and the formalization of "if and only if".

The usual way to state the above definition is to omit the **iff** and states it as :

> $f$ is *continuous* at point $c$ **if** ...

This means that we are saying : "$A$, if $B$", that is we are using the part : "if $B$, then $A$" of the *bi-conditional*, i.e. :

> **if** for all $\epsilon > 0$ ..., **then** $f$ is *continuous* at point $c$.

Why so ? because "usually" we have to apply the defining condition in order to prove the continuity.

Comment: Then why it is not written in my book and on wikipedia f continous iff [...] but it is written f continous if [...] ?

Comment: @user1594047 For some reason (I guess it is tradition) to write only "if" and not "iff". But definitions are if and only if statements; even if doesn't say so.