# What does "if and only if" mean in definitions?

Tags: soft-question

Consider the following definition:

> A sequence $\{p_n\}$ is Cauchy if we have that for every $n, m \ge N$: $$|p_n - p_m| < \epsilon$$

Although if and only if is not used, we know that if a sequence is Cauchy, the Cauchy criterion holds. Consider now the following definition:

> An action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is transitive if and only if for each $x, y \in X$ there is a $g \in G$ such that $gx = y$.

What motivates the use of "if and only if" here? As far as definitions go, my head has automatically thought "if and only if." The latter example is taken from Ratcliffe's "Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds", and he switches a lot between "if" and "if and only if" in his definitions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if

Comment: Yes, I do know what iff means. If you give me an example of a Cauchy sequence where the Cauchy criterion does not hold, I will be happy to delete this question.

Comment: I think definitions are always $\iff$ statements. For instance the **definition** $A\in M(n\times n)$ is invertible if there exists $B \in M(n\times n)$ such that $AB = BA = E_n$ can also be written, because is a definition, as $A\in M(n\times n)$ is invertible $: \iff$ there exists $B \in M(n\times n)$ such that $AB = BA = E_n$.

Personally i think the second option is better, because it avoids confusion.

Comment: You can also see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024552/logic-behind-continuity-definition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between "if" and "if and only if" in a definition. More precisely, in the context of a definition "if" should be read as a shorthand for "if and only if".

I can't comment about Ratcliffe specifically, but my guess is that the reason it appears E is using them interchangeably is because E is.

Comment: Hm, yes, that is what I have always thought, I just found it weird to use "iff" in a definition. Thanks!