# odd logical structures

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How you find contrapositive and converse of these sentences.

1. Only if John chops down the tree, will he be a lumberjack.
2. You can't win if you don't fight.
3. All people that root for the Ducks are from Oregon.

The logical has me thrown at where the if is happening so I can switch it around from p implies q to q implies p. Please help

Comment: See this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617562/conditional-statements-only-if) : So $A$ only if $B$ means $A \rightarrow B$.

Comment: See also [Converse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_%28logic%29) and [Contrapositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).

Comment: I did read those so this is the conclusion I came to for these

1. If john is Lumberjack, then he cut down the tree
contrapositive
    If john is not a lumberjack, then he did not cut down the tree.

2. Converse
   If you don't fight, then you can't win.
   Contrapositive
   If you do fight, then you can win.

3. Converse
   If person is from Oregon then they root for the Ducks.
  
   If person is not from Oregon, then they dont root for the Ducks.

are these correct?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have to rewrite 1) as :

> "Only if John chops down the tree, will he be a lumberjack"

as :

> **if** John will be a lumberjack, **then** he chops down the tree.

This one has the "logical form" : $p \rightarrow q$; thus, its **converse** ($q \rightarrow p$) will be :

> **if** John chops down the tree, **then** he will be a lumberjack,

while its **contrapositive** ($\lnot q \rightarrow \lnot p$)will be :

> **if** John does not chop down the tree, **then** he will not be a lumberjack.

---

For 2), we simply have :

> **if** you don't fight, **then** you can't win.

Thus, converse and contrapositive must be straightforward.

---

For 3), assuming that we have to "analyze" it without predicate logic, I agree with you :

> **if** a person roots for the Ducks, **then** he is from Oregon.

Again, having reduced it to the standard "logical form" : $p \rightarrow q$, we have only to apply the above formulae to get converse and contrapositive.

Comment: How would we rewrite the other two?

Comment: oh okay so this is what I came up with for 2 and 3

2. Converse
     If you can't win, then you didnt fight
   Contrapositive
      If you did win, then you did fight

3. If person is from Oregon, then he roots for the Ducks

   Contrapositive
     If person is not from Oregon, then person does not root for the Ducks