# How to transcribe the following statement into a predicate wff?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

There was a disagreement in my college class regarding what the following statement would be in a predicate wff format:

It is always a sunny day only if it is a rainy day.

Where D(*x*) is "*x* is a day", S(*x*) is "*x* is sunny", and R(*x*) is "*x* is rainy".

Is there anyone who can help settle this?

UPDATE: I notice some people may be tempted to suggest alterations to the sentence. I agree with this, as it is an awkwardly written sentence. What makes its current structure significant is that the sentence is quoted directly from a question in a textbook my class was discussing.

Comment: $a \text{ only if } b \dashv \vdash a \implies b$, if that helps.

Comment: See this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617562/conditional-statements-only-if) : "$A$ only if $B$" must be symbolized as : $A \rightarrow B$. Thus : "It is a sunny day only if it is a rainy day" is : "**if** it is a sunny day, **then** it is a rainy day".

Comment: If we want to use predicate logic, we must have something like : $\forall x (S(x) \rightarrow R(x))$, where the domain of quantification is the set $D$ of days.

Comment: Is that the right statement?  Are you sure you don't want: "It is always a sunny day only if it is **never** a rainy day".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "It is always a sunny day only if it is a rainy day."

To paraphrase: 
"If anything is a day and it is sunny, then it must be a day and it is rainy."
$$\forall x \Big((D(x)\wedge S(x))\to (D(x) \wedge R(x))\Big)$$

Though we might be tempted to simplify:  "if anything is a day, then if it is sunny, then it must be rainy".
$$\forall x \Big(D(x)\to \big(S(x))\to R(x)\big)\Big)$$

$$\forall x \in D: \big(S(x))\to R(x)\big)$$

---

However, I *suspect* that something was missing from the original statement.

Perhaps it was : "It is always a sunny day only if it is *never* a rainy day."

$$\forall x \big(D(x)\to S(x)\big) \to \neg\exists x \big(D(x)\wedge R(x)\big)$$

Comment: I added some more information regarding the structure of the sentence. I hope that helps clear the air a bit.