# Need an intuitive example for how "P is necessary for Q" means "Q$\implies$P"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, computer-science

I am confused about how "P is necessary for Q" means "Q$\implies$P" (source: Kenneth Rosen DMGT).

Intuitively, I interpret "P is necessary for Q" as "for Q to happen, P must happen", which I basically feel is equivalent to "if P happens then Q must occur", i.e, "P $\implies$ Q". Could someone correct my understanding?

Comment: "Having money is necessary to buy milk" means "If I bought milk it implies I must have had money". It does not necessarily mean "If I have money I will go to buy milk", maybe not.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018188/using-terms-necessary-and-sufficient-when-writing-proofs-for-logical-equival)

Comment: "P is necessary for Q" means that we cannot have Q without P, i.e. the circumstance that Q holds and P does not is ruled out. This fir with the line marked False in the truth table of $Q \to P$.

Comment: Another example: "In order to get a driver's license, it is necessary to pass a vision test."

Comment: *"for Q to happen, P must happen"* --- Doesn't this mean "when Q happens, then P must happen", which is Q $\implies$ P?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is an intuitive example:

> Suppose that it is **necessary** to have a ticket ($P$) in order to board a certain train ($Q$).  That is, **if** you board the train ($Q$), **then** you have a ticket ($P$).

(It is *not* true that if you have a ticket ($P$) then you boarded the train ($Q$)!  You might have a ticket and fail to board, or you might have a ticket and be refused boarding because you would not extinguish your cigarette.)

Answer (score 3):

> I interpret `P is necessary for Q` as `for Q to`**`happen`**`, P must happen`, which I basically feel is equivalent to `if P happens then Q must`**`occur`**, i.e, `P ⟹ Q`.

1. `P is necessary for Q` means `P must be the case for Q to be the case`, which can be rewritten as `for Q to be the case, P must be the case`, which means `if Q is true, then P is true`, i.e., `Q ⟹ P`.
2. You were likely thrown off by erroneously framing P and Q as events that “happen/occur” and by the phrasing “for Q to happen / come true / be the case”, which sounds like “to cause Q to happen”, which in turn sounds like “implies Q”.

   However, P and Q are of course just (true/false) statements, and there is no inherent sense of time or causation when discussing these truths/falsities.
3. Thus, for example,

   - persistence is necessary for success (i.e., success ⟹ persistence)

   should be understood not as

   - ❌ persistence **results in** success,

   or even as

   - ❌ success **results in** persistence,

   but as

   - ✔️ success **is evidence of** persistence.
4. To put it another way,

   - persistence is necessary for success (i.e., success ⟹ persistence)

   most assuredly means

   - if got no persistence, then surely got no success,

   which is logically equivalent to

   - if got success, then got persistence.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks. I understood my mistake of looking at these statements as timed events, rather than just simple english statements.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand that the material conditional is *not* saying anything about temporal or causal relationships ... it *merely* says that 'if this is true, then that is true'

Consider:

"In order to take Calculus II ($II$), it is necessary that you take Calculus I ($I$). "

*Temporally* you might think $I \to II$, but that is not right: I can take Calculus I without taking Calculus II.  But what we *do* have is $II \to I$:  if it is true that I take (or have taken)  Calculus II, then we can infer that I must have taken Calculus I.

Answer (score 1):

To get the intuitive idea you can think of it in simple logic, and avoid symbols:

$ Q \Rightarrow P  $ means that at every single case that $Q$ holds, then $P$ will certainly hold as well. So there is not even a single case in which $Q$ holds but $P$ doesn't. So $P$ is *necessary* for $Q$, as it always holds given the fact that $Q$ holds. Or in other words, $Q$ **cannot** hold, if $P$ doesn't hold. That's what makes $P$ *necessary* for $Q$.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? Wonderful community, this is. Someone tries to be helpful (without committing any errors, as far as I can tell) and it's voted down.

Comment: @SimonSMN Thanks for noticing. I don't get it as well. I've figured that the community can become way too toxic at times.

Comment: @SimonSMN unexplained downvotes are something you just have to get used to on StackExchange sites as the accepted ethos doesn't require a down-voter to give any kind of reason (not like when you vote to close a post). If you are being plagued by down-votes on multiple questions or answers, it is worth flagging the apparent hate campaign. If it's just the odd one or two, then that's just life.

Answer (score -1):

Consider that $(A\implies B)\Longleftrightarrow (\neg B\implies \neg A)$, so that it is necessary for $B$ to be true in order that $A$ might be true. For example, let $A$ denote that $x$ is a natural number and $B$ denote that $x$ is a real number. Clearly $A\implies B$ because every natural number is a real number. But if $x$ is not a real number, then it is certainly not a natural number: it is necessary that $x$ be real for it to possibly be natural, and so $B$ is necessary for $A$.

On the other hand, if $A\implies B$, then $A$ is sufficient for $B$: it is sufficient that $x$ be a natural number for it to be a real number.